# Client-Side Filtering of a CheckBox List

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, autocomplete, filter, checkboxlist

I have a checkbox list which contains more than 100 entries. I need a filter option for the checkbox list.

The desired functionality would be that when I type in the filter TextBox, the contents of the CheckBox list will be filtered based on the text that was entered (similar to autocomplete).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use jQuery, or a similar client-side JavaScript framework to set up an `OnBlur` event for your filtering `Input` box, so that when its text changes, it shows/hides the specific items in the CheckBox list based on matches between the text that has been entered, and `Attribute` values for the individual `CheckBox` entries. Without seeing your specific html setup, can't be more specific than that.